# htaccess redirect error in domain example.com:443

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I've got a problem with a htaccess redirect.

What I like to do:

I want to redirect the link `https://www.example.com/folder` to `https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder`.

So normally I would use:

```
redirect /folder /folder/subfolder
```

But I've got the problem, that my browser is redirected to `http://www.example.com:443/folder/subfolder`. So no `https` but a nice `:443` at the end. And the browser gives me an 404 error.

Does anybody has an idea how I can redirect the url correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
redirect permanent /folder https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder
```

**EDIT:** If mod_alias isn't working for you you can try using mod_rewrite based rule like this:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder/?$ https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem still exists.

Comment: What problem? You mean it is still being redirected to: `http:// www.example.com:443/folder/subfolder`?

Comment: Yes, its still being redirect to this link.

Comment: That points me to some misconfig in somewhere in your setup. When you type this URL in browser tell me what happens: `https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder`

Comment: If I open example.com/folder/subfolder I see the page and the link begins with https://. But if I try your new code (and even if I say it should redicret to Google) it shows me http://www.example.com:443/folder

htaccess and mod_rewrite are both enabled. The .htaccess is in the root folder of my site.

Comment: Well as you can see there is no mention of 443 in .htaccess mosted here which means something else is causing this. It's difficult for an outsider to debug this. You can enab;e RewriteLog and see what's going on. Good luck.